# Spark Streaming-Receiver drops data

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I'm using spark streaming to process data. I do a simple flatMap on each record as follows

```
package bb;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.streaming.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;


public class ReceiverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Receiver Test");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

        //JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> inputStream = jssc.receiverStream(new JavaCustomReceiver("localhost", 3081));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> inputStream = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 3081);


        JavaPairDStream<String, String> bab = inputStream.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(String t) {

                ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
                System.out.println(t);
                if (t.length() > 2) return ret;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                    String str = t + i;
                    ret.add(new Tuple2("", str));

                    Socket socket = null;
                    PrintWriter pw = null;
                    try {
                        socket=new Socket("spark000",3081);
                        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                        pw.println(str);
                        pw.flush();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            pw.close();
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }
        });

        bab.print();

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

For each record s, {"s0", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"} will be produced if length(s) <= 2. The new records are sent back to the socket server to be further processed.

At the start, I send an "1" to the socket server. In the worker log (I'm using one machine so there is only one worker), I expect to see the following result (may in different order I think):
1
10
11
12
13
14
100
101
102
103
104
110
111
112
...
143
144

However, the result is as follows
1
10
11
12
100
101
102
103
104
110
111
112
113
114
120
121
122
123
124

Namely "13" and "14" are not processed in flatMap.
I've also tried a custom receiver(the first sample in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/streaming-custom-receivers.html) instead of socketTextStream(). The guide says that store(single-record) is not reliable but store(multiple-records) is reliable, thus I changed that part to

```
while (!isStopped() && (userInput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ArrayList<String> lt = new ArrayList<String>();
    lt.add(userInput);
    store(lt.iterator());
}
```

But I still see data loss.

Actually I saw a similar question ([Spark custom streaming dropping most of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417092/spark-custom-streaming-dropping-most-of-the-data)), but the answer didn't seem to solve that.
Can anyone spot the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the solution how to fix that?